# how to get count of array outside tableview method swift

Tags: swift

I want to increase UIView size according to array count. Currently, I am doing this -:

```
var socialMediaURLSArray = [URL]()
```

and in View did load i am doing this -:

```
 viewHeightConstraints.constant = (60 * 1) + 170
```

In place of 1, I want to define socialMediaURLSArray count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In place of 1, I want to define socialMediaURLSArray count.

so

```
viewHeightConstraints.constant = (60 * socialMediaURLSArray.count) + 170
```

You may need to to the above code inside the `didSet` of the `socialMediaURLSArray` to make it auto update.

<sub>You may need to call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` to update the constraint. Also you can perform it inside an `animation` block</sub>

Comment: it always show socialMediaURLSArray.count = 0

Comment: Are you appending urls to the `socialMediaURLSArray` ?